# What are the best way to pass server-side variables to other server

Tags: web-applications

What are the best way to pass server-side variables to other server especially when we need to pass some sensitive info. Here are the option I can see

setHeader and getHeader 
setAttribute and getAttribute - Heard that this will work within the same server

Is there any other way where we can pass the sensitive information over servers?

Comment: local or remote servers? is not enought to create a SSL conenction?

Comment: You can use https://jwt.io/

Comment: @Fran, it is remote server, running on https

Comment: @ezhil then you can simply rely on SSL (TLS 1.2) security

Comment: @Fran, Any good reference link, material you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by others, there are multiples solutions to pass informations between servers.

With SSL, headers of the request are encrypted.

I think the response of the question is not really about the security, but about what kind of data you want to protect.

According to the nature of your data, it possibily makes no sense to put it into your headers.

Comment: Agree, It is not good idea to put my data in header. What is the correct option to sent the data?

Comment: It's not exacly what I said.
Usually, you can put authentication stuff in headers (like tokens).
But if this is just information you send one time, like a super private message, put it in the body of the request.